# React - Fetch request not sending content in body

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, fetch

I'm not getting data in body object from `fetch` request on my server side. I've tried other solutions on SO but nothing is working so far in my case. I'm using Node express on backend and React on frontend.

in component:

```
addCity = _ => {
    const { city } = this.state;
    fetch('http://localhost:3003/city_create', {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        create_name: city.name,
        create_district: city.district,
        create_population: city.population
      })
    })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.getCities;
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))

  }
```

server route:

```
router.post('/city_create', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Trying to create new city...")
    const { create_name, create_district, create_population } = req.body;
    //debugger
    const queryString = "INSERT INTO city (Name, District, Population, CountryCode) VALUES (?,?,?,'PAK')";

    getConnection().query(queryString, [create_name, create_district, create_population], (err, rows, fields) => {
        console.log(create_name, create_district, create_population);
        if (err) {
            console.log('A db error occurred:' + err);
            res.sendStatus(500);
            return;
            //throw err;
        }
        console.log("Inserted a new City with Id: ", rows.insertId);
    });

    res.end();
});
```

tried using `FormData` and `accept` property in header as well but no luck.

Comment: have you used `body-parser` in node.js ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install `body-parser` module to extract the entire body portion of an incoming request stream and exposes it on req.body.

It was part of express earlier, now we need to install separately.

`npm install body-parser --save`

and use the middleware as :

`app.use(bodyParser.json())`

Comment: Thanks man. It worked. I was using:
`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));` Can you tell me what's the difference?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions this explains it